# How to transform and other actions activated instantly after press in industry compatible mode?

Tags: keymap

When you turn your keymap scheme to industry compatible after pressing <kbd>W</kbd> for move, nothing happens. But if I press <kbd>G</kbd> in Blender native scheme, the object instantly starts moving with my mouse. How to implement this in industry compatible mode?

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting, but for me in this mode `W` activates the move gizmo, then you need to use it

Comment: I want it to work like in native keymap scheme. When you press button and object instanlty starts moving with your mouse. Right now it works differently, i press W and after that i need to press mouse3 to move object. So basically i do one more action to get result which is annoying.

Comment: Agreed, that is annoying... You could simply change your keymap in the native scheme from `G` to `W`  
Or have a look at how the `G` on works and adapt it to the `W` one?

Comment: Im on industry mode, because i prefer navigation scheme with Alt, like in other software. Yes, thats what im trying to figure out rn, how it works in native.